# Can not save multiple product variation fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I save the first product variation fields they are saved, but when I try to save the second, third, forth and further they do not get saved.

I am filling out the SKU for every product variation as well, so it should work. But obv it is something I am missing here? This is the latest WordPress and latest WooCommerce version.

```
//Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variable_fields', 10, 3 );

//Save variation fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variable_fields', 10, 1 );


/**
 * Create new fields for variations
 *
 */
function variable_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php
        // Textarea
        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
            array(
                'id'          => '_textarea['.$loop.']',
                'label'       => __( 'Contains', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'description' => __( '<br />Contains', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_textarea', true ),
            )
        );
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <?php
        // Textarea
        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
            array(
                'id'          => '_textarea_2['.$loop.']',
                'label'       => __( 'Observation message', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'description' => __( '<br />Observation message', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_textarea_2', true ),
            )
        );
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
}


/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
 */
function save_variable_fields( $post_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['variable_sku'] ) ) :

        $variable_sku          = $_POST['variable_sku'];
        $variable_post_id      = $_POST['variable_post_id'];

        // Textarea
        $_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $_textarea[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_textarea', stripslashes( $_textarea[$i] ) );
            }
        endfor;


        // Textarea
        $_textarea_2 = $_POST['_textarea_2'];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $_textarea_2[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_textarea_2', stripslashes( $_textarea_2[$i] ) );
            }
        endfor;

    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified action & function for saving:

```
//Save variation fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variable_fields', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
 */
function save_variable_fields( $variation_id, $i ) {
    if ( empty( $variation_id ) ) return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['_textarea'][$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_textarea', stripslashes( $_POST['_textarea'][$i] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['_textarea_2'][$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_textarea_2', stripslashes( $_POST['_textarea_2'][$i] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I've tested this code with your html code written above & it was working. Have you made any modification in this code before using?

Comment: No, I used exact that code. I can edit the first variable, but not 2nd and further. Same problem as I had with my old code.